# Unable to remove java-11-amazon-corretto-devel from Fedora 30

Tags: java, linux, rpm, uninstallation, java-11

I'm trying to remove Amazon Corretto from fedora 30 distro

but im getting below error:

[root@smaini ~]# dnf remove java-11-amazon-corretto-devel

Remove  1 Package

Freed space: 306 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y

Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                                                               1/1 
  Running scriptlet: java-11-amazon-corretto-devel-1:11.0.5.10-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                            1/1

failed to read link /usr/bin/javac: No such file or directory
error: %preun(java-11-amazon-corretto-devel-1:11.0.5.10-1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 2

Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package java-11-amazon-corretto-devel
  Verifying        : java-11-amazon-corretto-devel-1:11.0.5.10-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                            1/1

Failed:
  java-11-amazon-corretto-devel-1:11.0.5.10-1.x86_64

Error: Transaction failed

Please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the scriptlet of `java-11-amazon-corretto-devel`. You cannot do anything about it. Beside reporting it to author of that package.

You can check the scriptlet using: `rpm -q --scripts java-11-amazon-corretto-devel`

You can remove the package without running the scripts (with all implications): `rpm -e --noscripts java-11-amazon-corretto-devel`